# Unable to retrive data from Bundle

Tags: android

I am trying to retrive some data that I have added to the bundle but I am unable to retrive it using the normal way it is done.

My current code which works is

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();    
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                    Object value = "start_color";
                    start_color = String.format("%s", key);                
                }
```

This gets me the bundle value, but when I use a standard code like this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
  if (bundle != null) 
   {
     String value = bundle.getString("start_color");
   }
```

Is unable to get the bundle values I am confused why this is happening!! Can some1 tell me why this is happening?

This is the code where I am putting value into the Bundle

```
String rgbString = "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color);

                //Change activity send data
                Intent device = new Intent(v.getContext(), Create_Preset.class);
                device.putExtra(rgbString,"start_color");
                startActivity(device);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

I even added new rows into my preset table using the altered code via a REST API so those wondering if the bundle has any value, YES IT DOES!!

Here is the select on the database I am storing the values see the `start_color` and `end_color` those are the values I am getting from the bundle

> ```
> Host: localhost
> Database: led
> Generation Time: Jan 17, 2015 at 04:37 PM
> Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.2.7.1 / MySQL 5.6.20
> SQL query: SELECT * FROM `preset` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 25 ;
> Rows: 2
> Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
> preset    starttime_hour  starttime_min   endtime_hour    endtime_min     startColor  endColor
> test  12  0   12  0   R: 159 B: 159 G: 159    R: 159 B: 159 G: 159
> test2     12  0   12  0   R: 39 B: 122 G: 91  R: 39 B: 122 G: 91
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that the bundle contains the value? Show thet code where you put the value in the bundle

Comment: @Marcus the bundle contains the value how else am I getting it with the altered code?

Comment: You are inverting the key and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the value as the key and the key as the value.

Correct:
Intent.putExtra(key, value)

What you have:
device.putExtra(rgbString, "start_color");

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Iterator interface to get values from the key set as bundle.keySet returns a Set of Strings. 
For eg

```
Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
Iterator<String> itr = keys.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
                String key = itr.next();
                String value = bundle.get(key);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect and irrelevant. The foreach loop works for all `Iterable` implementations.